# 2d dynamic characters with animation?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

So I'm trying to have a dynamic character builder in my iOS app and the cocos2d library, where you can control the character after and perform animations with.

Is it possible? I know animations are done with Sprite Sheets.. is it possible to have a sprite sheet of positions that the new character would emulate?

Or would I need to create each variation of each possible character and the sprite sheet of animations along with that?

Or is there a totally different way that I don't know about/can't think of??

Comment: Sprite sheet = texture atlas = collection of images. You need an image per animation frame. To make the animation dynamic you would animate individual body parts using individual images as per whatever logic you require to animate said body.

Comment: Actually, try to describe what animation effect do you want to achieve. Then we can suggest a way to implement it.

Comment: Well, I would at LEAST need a walking animation for the dynamic character. There would probably would be a pickup item animation/press an object animation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what I did to accomplish this was to build the character out of multiple black and white sprite sheets. One for hair, eyes, shirt, pants, etc.  Then when you user selects the color for everything I color the images of each body part dynamically according to their selections.

Seems to work well so far, haven't done performance testing though.